# Creating Rectangle around Bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap

I have an bitmap of 10*15 size now i want to create an bitmap from this existing bitmap with size 20*30 but the increased area should be transparent ,bitmap should not be translated/scaled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(
    yourBitmap,
    xMarginYouWant,
    yMarginYouWant,
    yourBitmap.getWidth() + xMarginYouWant * 2,
    yourBitmap.getHeight() + yMarginYouWant * 2
);
```

Answer (score 1):

I did not get your question....
The heading is "drawing rectangle around bitmap" but there is no description for rectangle in detail.
If you want a rectangle then this can be done as follows....

```
RectF rect = new RectF(x,y,x+width,y+height);  
canvas.drawRect(rect, paint);
```

Drawing bitmap refer other answers...

Answer (score 0):

Create a new `Bitmap` that's 20x30, create a `Canvas` to hold that bitmap, and then `Canvas.drawBitmap()` your 10x15 one into it.

Answer (score 0):

Create first bitmap with this method:

```
Bitmap b=b.createBitmap (Bitmap source, int x, int y, int width, int height);
```

Give your height and width and proper x and y values.